# trouble with error function

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error

Im currently doing Programming principles and practices using C++ and i don't quite understand how to use the error function as it was used in the book.

the function is

```
inline void error(const string& s)
{
    throw runtime_error(s);
}
```

which was included in the std_lib_facilities header file.

This is a small program that utilizes it.

```
int main() 
{ 
    cout << "Please enter expression (we can handle +, –, *, and /)\n"; 
    cout << "add an x to end expression (e.g., 1+2*3x): "; 
    int lval = 0; 
    int rval; 
    cin>>lval;                                     // read leftmost operand 
        if (!cin) error("no first operand"); 
        for (char op; cin>>op; ) {          // read operator and right-hand operand 
                                                               // repeatedly 
            if (op!='x') cin>>rval; 
            if (!cin) error("no second operand"); 
            switch(op) 
            { 
               case '+': 
                   lval += rval;               // add: lval = lval + rval 
                   break; 
               case '–': 
                   lval –= rval;               // subtract: lval = lval – rval 
                   break; 
               case '*': 
                   lval *= rval;           // multiply: lval = lval * rval 
                   break; 
               case '/': 
                   lval /= rval;            // divide: lval = lval / rval 
                   break; 
               default:                           // not another operator: print result 
                   cout << "Result: " << lval << '\n'; 
                   keep_window_open(); 
                   return 0; 
             } 
         } 
     error("bad expression");
}
```

My question is, how is this error function suppose to work if there isn't a catch to catch the error when its thrown so that your message can be displayed.

Comment: In the code you've shown, if `error()` is called it will end up aborting the program then and there. I'm not sure I'd consider this falling within the meaning of the term "work", exactly. I'd say perhaps now might be a good time to start looking for a better book.

Comment: As I recall, Stroustrup designed the header as something to be used for the first couple weeks of learning so that starting off would be easier without needing to know later concepts yet. Anyway, when an exception is uncaught, your implementation may print the message.

Comment: If there is no `catch` then the program terminates. Your compiler may or may not decide to display the message. You could add a catch handler around main.

Comment: "In std_lib_facilities.h we supply an error() function that by default terminates the program with a system error message plus the string we passed as an argument to error()."

It's just a little confusing is all. I know that if you add the catch statement it will work as intended, just wanted  to ask if i missed something.

Answer (score 0):

To *ensure* that the error message is printed you need to do that yourself, rather than relying on Quality Of Implementation.

Like,

```
#include <iostream>      // std::cout, std::cerr
#include <stdexcept>     // std::runtime_error
#include <stdlib.h>      // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string>        // std::string
using namespace std;

auto fail( string const& s ) -> bool { throw runtime_error( s ); }

void cpp_main()
{
    // What you would otherwise put directly in `main`, e.g.
    cout << "x? ";
    double x;
    cin >> x
        || fail( "Uh oh, that was not a valid value for x." );
}

auto main() -> int
{
    try
    {
        cpp_main();  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Disclaimer: code untouched by compilers' hands.

---

Tip: you can use the free AStyle formatter to fix the formatting of your code.